# Remover espaços de uma string a partir da segunda ocorrência

Tags: javascript, string, regex

Atualmente estou removendo espaços usando um simples `replace()` e adicionando um espaço que obrigatoriamente tenho de preservar entre o terceiro e quarto caractere usando `substr()`

```js
let str = 'abc defghijk lmnop qrstuv wx y z'

str = str.replace(/\s+/g, '')
// resultado: 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

str = str.substr(0, 3) + ' ' + str.substr(3, str.length)

console.log(str)
```

Qual a forma mais sucinta de se chegar ao mesmo resultado usando apenas o método `replace()`?

---

PS: eu realmente tenho pouco conhecimento sobre o uso de `RegExp`

Comment: Você quer voltar a string como ela era?

Comment: Não, quero remover todos os espaços más preservando o primeiro

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Utilizando apenas `replace` também dá para fazer, se bem que provavelmente não compensa em relação a performance/legibilidade/suporte.

Pode utilizar a seguinte regex:

```
(?<=\s.*)\s+
```

Explicação:

```
(?<=   - Positive lookbehind, que tenha algo atrás
\s+.*) - Que tenha espaço seguido de qualquer coisa
\s+    - O espaço a ser capturado
```

[Veja esta regex no regex101](https://regex101.com/r/GEvZLS/1)

Então pode ler esta regex como capturar um espaço que tenha outro espaço atrás seguido de qualquer coisa. Por este motivo não irá apanhar o primeiro pois esse não tem nenhum espaço para trás.

Vale lembrar que isto usa *positive lookbehind*, que foi acrescentado ao javascript à pouco tempo e por isso é provável que não funcione em navegadores mais antigos. A segunda nota é que este é um *lookbehind* de tamanho variável que a maior parte dos *regex engines* de outras linguagens nem suporta.

Exemplo:

```js
let str = 'abc defghijk lmnop qrstuv wx y z'

str = str.replace(/(?<=\s+.*)\s+/g, '')

console.log(str)
```

Por isso acho que melhor solução é mesmo fazer o simples e utilizar um `indexOf` como sugerido para obter o primeiro espaço e substituir a partir daí.

Comment: Eu gostei da resposta, bem mais sucinta. Um teste rápido no jsperf.com mostrou ser mais rápido que usando `indexOf()`. Estou usando sintaxe ES6 e por isso uso Babel ... vou testar usando o plugin [babel-plugin-transform-modern-regexp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-modern-regexp) e poder contribuir com o resultado para esta resposta caso a aceite.

Comment: @LauroMoraes Isso é interessante. Eu não testei performance, mas estaria à espera que fosse mais lento que o `indexOf`. Desconhecia essa extensão do babel, mas se suportar este tipo de regexes então acaba por ser uma boa solução.

Comment: Atualmente só as versões mais recentes de Chrome e Node suportam nativamente **lookbehind**, infelizmente o módulo citado anteriormente para Babel possui um ISSUE ainda não tratado ou seja, ainda não é possível portar via Babel..."garimpei bastante" más, parece que não há outro módulo que atenda esta necessidade. Nenhum pollyfill também infelizmente. O teste supracitado foi utilizando Chrome 68. Agradeço novamente a boa resposta.

Answer (score 6):

Você pode capturar a posição do primeiro espaço com o `indexOf()`, reservar esse prefixo, e reduzir o escopo do seu `replace()`, mas aí a solução não é através do regex.

```js
let str = 'abc defghijk lmnop qrstuv wx y z';
let prefix = str.substr(0,str.indexOf(' ')+1);

str = prefix + str.substr(prefix.length).replace(/\s+/g, '');

console.log(str);
//abc defghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Answer (score 2):

### Split + Join

Uma alternativa para manter o primeiro espaço é usar `Split` com o `Join`.

```js
let str = 'abc defghijk lmnop qrstuv wx y z'

tokens = str.split(' ')

str = tokens[0] + ' ' + tokens.slice(1).join('')

console.log(str)
```

Explicando o código:

1. Separa o texto num array usando o caractere de espaço como separador.
2. Pega o primeiro texto mais 1 espaço e junta com o restante do texto sem os espaços.